# Debug only one Thread in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

i have many threads running in my application, but
i want to debug just only  one thread. i'm using  eclipse, is that possible? i just saw that stuff in visual studio and in c#

Thank you for your help and pacience.

Comment: After you have created a breakpoint you can limit it to a particular thread within the breakpoint properties.

Answer (score 2):

Identify the thread that you want to debug and name it using `currentThread().setName("myThreadName")`. Then set a conditional breakpoint on `currentThread().getName.equals("myThreadName")`.

Take care though as thread pooling can introduce some complications to your debugging process.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the debug perspective, the window on the top left ("Debug") will list all the threads and let you pause them individually.